# Keycloak roles and JWT granted authorities

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

We have a working application in production and we were asked to validate the audience on the token and create custom audiences for the clients, so the Keycloak verification of this field is not very helpful.
So I have been referring to this documentation to customize the SecurityConfig: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html .

Now I can verify the aud token succesfully but now I have a problem with the fact that now, instead of using `org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount` for checking the `SecurityFilterChain` I now have `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` because I added `http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);` to be able to customize the aud validator meaning that I now have to deal with granted authorities.

It is now failing because it says what I have on the scope doesn't match the roles that are on the `SecurityFilterChain` and of course they won't. Roles are a completely different claim.

I understand that I can change the authorities, according to the same documentation I linked above, I can't seem to tell it to get claim from where it should because of the format of the token.

The claims I have look like this:

```
{sub=316232a4-2054-4b98-ab28-756cf767fa64, 
resource_access={"account":{"roles":["manage-account","manage-account-links","view-profile"]}},
clientHost=192.168.0.126, 
email_verified=false, 
clientId=test-client, 
iss=https://url.net/auth/realms/app, 
typ=Bearer, 
preferred_username=service-account-test-backoffice, 
clientAddress=192.168.0.126, aud=[kibana, account], 
acr=1, 
nbf=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, 
realm_access={"roles":["backoffice","offline_access","uma_authorization"]}, <<-These are the ones I want to access 
azp=test-client, 
auth_time=0, 
scope=email profile, 
exp=2023-05-05T13:34:23Z, 
session_state=8b2877a3-9e04-44b2-8f52-43e079c446a9, 
iat=2023-05-05T13:14:23Z, 
jti=db589f9d-44d1-4bc0-813c-e34617b3ba64}
```

I tried several things, among them this:

```
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("realm_access[roles]");
```

And I have not been able to use that claim.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This it what it says the type of the claim is:
[image]

Comment: I ended up changing in keycloak the claim so now it is simply roles instead of realm_access={"roles": ...}

Comment: You know that Keycloak can send roles in multiple claims, right? Roles can be defined (and granted) at realm level, but also at client one: `resource_access.{client-id}.roles`. Your tick won't with client roles.

Answer (score 0):

Sample authorities mapper reading from any claims (not just one claim and not just at root level in JSON tree) taken from [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server):

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
static class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    private final SpringAddonsProperties.IssuerProperties properties;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        return Stream.of(properties.claims).flatMap(claimProperties -> {
            Object claim;
            try {
                claim = JsonPath.read(jwt.getClaims(), claimProperties.jsonPath);
            } catch (PathNotFoundException e) {
                claim = null;
            }
            if (claim == null) {
                return Stream.empty();
            }
            if (claim instanceof String claimStr) {
                return Stream.of(claimStr.split(","));
            }
            if (claim instanceof String[] claimArr) {
                return Stream.of(claimArr);
            }
            if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(claim.getClass())) {
                final var iter = ((Collection) claim).iterator();
                if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                    return Stream.empty();
                }
                final var firstItem = iter.next();
                if (firstItem instanceof String) {
                    return (Stream<String>) ((Collection) claim).stream();
                }
                if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(firstItem.getClass())) {
                    return (Stream<String>) ((Collection) claim).stream().flatMap(colItem -> ((Collection) colItem).stream()).map(String.class::cast);
                }
            }
            return Stream.empty();
        }).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast).toList();
    }
}
```

It is using this `@ConfigurationProperties`

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring-addons")
public class SpringAddonsProperties {
    private IssuerProperties[] issuers = {};

    @Data
    static class IssuerProperties {
        private URL uri;

        @NestedConfigurationProperty
        private ClaimMappingProperties[] claims;

        private String usernameJsonPath = JwtClaimNames.SUB;

        @Data
        static class ClaimMappingProperties {
            private String jsonPath;
            private CaseProcessing caseProcessing = CaseProcessing.UNCHANGED;
            private String prefix = "";

            static enum CaseProcessing {
                UNCHANGED, TO_LOWER, TO_UPPER
            }
        }
    }

    public IssuerProperties get(URL issuerUri) throws MisconfigurationException {
        final var issuerProperties = Stream.of(issuers).filter(iss -> issuerUri.equals(iss.getUri())).toList();
        if (issuerProperties.size() == 0) {
            throw new MisconfigurationException("Missing authorities mapping properties for %s".formatted(issuerUri.toString()));
        }
        if (issuerProperties.size() > 1) {
            throw new MisconfigurationException("Too many authorities mapping properties for %s".formatted(issuerUri.toString()));
        }
        return issuerProperties.get(0);
    }

    static class MisconfigurationException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5887967904749547431L;

        public MisconfigurationException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

And the best part is that I already publish, on maven-central, an enhanced Spring Boot Starter with which all you have to provide for authorities mapping are application properties: JSON path to the role claims and transformations to apply (prefix and case). [Sample there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default): [OAuth2SecurityConfig](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/OAuth2SecurityConfig.java), is there only to demo access control using `AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry` (the reset of the access control is done with `@PreAuthorize` on [`@Controller`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/ed1e8da796dafd667ae5f308d05d62726066449c/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/GreetingController.java#L29), [`@Service`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/ed1e8da796dafd667ae5f308d05d62726066449c/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/MessageService.java#L30) and [`@Repository`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/ed1e8da796dafd667ae5f308d05d62726066449c/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/SecretRepo.java#L8)). Authorities mapping is done based on [application.yaml](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/ed1e8da796dafd667ae5f308d05d62726066449c/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/main/resources/application.yml#L26) (as well as CORS configuration, sessions and CSRF disabling, public resources definitions and more).